Using ShapeableImageView in Android works fine，But it alaways reports errors
The error information is as follows：
enter image description here
I traced the error code in this line:
 baseColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.ColorStateListItem_android_color, Color.MAGENTA);

I want to know how to solve this problem,Thanks.
I expect it to work without report errors.

R.styleable.ColorStateListItem_android_color is not defined anywhere.
